# WindowsError(3, 'The system cannot find the path specified')

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I'm getting the following exception on the line below *sometimes*:

```
WindowsError(3, 'The system cannot find the path specified')
```

There are a total of about 1956 pdf files (in path previously defined) and the exception is thrown on 43 of them. I don't see any pattern in the path & file name of those with the exception.
Any suggestions as to what the problem is?

```
totalBytes = 0
if pdfFile.endswith(".pdf") and \
   (" permit " in pdfFile or " Permit " in pdfFile): 

    filename = os.path.join(root, pdfFile)
    try:
        absolutePath = os.path.abspath(filename)
        print ("absolutePath", absolutePath)
        # exception on this line, occasionally:
        numberOfBytes = os.path.getsize(absolutePath)
        print ("numberOfBytes", numberOfBytes)
        totalBytes += numberOfBytes
    except WindowsError as windowsError:
        print (windowsError, filename)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get around the 256-character limit with one weird trick: prepend `\\?\` to the absolute filename. Escape those slashes, of course: `"\\\\?\\"`.

See also: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx). TL;DR, a different filename parser is used for names starting with `\\?\` that has different limitations.

Comment: I encountered this while working with some code within web2py. Thanks to your answer was able to resolve it.